# Azure API Management Developer Portal

Tags: api, azure, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

I have a requirement to expose the APIM Developer Portal to external partners, I want the developer portal to be my one stop shop for these partners to access and learn everything they need to know about my APIs, in the main APIM Developer Portal satisfies that requirement but when I want to add new content e.g. specific design, architecture, user guide documentation etc about the API it starts to get very confusing, for a start it looks like the depreciated publisher portal (which still exists) is the only place that I can add new pages.  The new pages seem very limited and clunky and cannot be amended in the new version of the portal.  There is also very limited documentation outside the standard MS stuff and nearky all of that relates to amending the current pages and templates.

My site will go live at the end of the year and I don't want to find one day these new content pages missing from the portal and my supporting documentation removed.

Does anybody know where Microsoft is going with the developer portal for customizing outside outside the standard templates they offer or can anybody supply me with a link of documentation that addresses new content pages?

Answer (score 2):

> It looks like the depreciated publisher portal (which still exists) is the only place that I can add new pages

Yes, you need to use the publisher portal to add new pages.

> The new pages seem very limited and clunky and cannot be amended in
>   the new version of the portal.

What do you mean by new version of the portal?

> I am going live at the end of the year and I don't want to find one day these new content pages missing from the portal and my supporting documentation removed.

If your worry is that API Management will automatically remove your content because of publisher portal deprecation - you can rest assured this is not going to happen, especially without any previous notice.

> Does anybody know where Microsoft is going with the developer portal for customizing outside the standard templates they offer?

There is some work planned to refresh the developer portal. Can you please elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve? What is your goal?

Answer (score 1):

One can edit those pages in 2 places: `Publisher Portal` and `Developer Portal`.

In the Publisher portal you can add widgets to predefined areas on the page. For example you can add a HTML widget to the home page for authenticated and non-authenticated users. Rasmas Gude has a great article about that [here](https://rasmusg.net/2018/11/22/azure-api-management-hiding-developer-portal-from-anonymous-users/).

In the Developer Portal you can change the information shown on each page by editing the template. There's a edit template icon available on the left for administrator. If you click that and then select the section you want to edit a split screen will appear below. The left have is DotLiquid markup and the right is the data model for that section. With that information you should be able to modify the page in the manner you wish.

Answer (score 0):

If they are decommissioning the publisher portal, it will be enabled in the azure portal. Earlier we have the API, Products and users etc in the publisher portal. that are added in the other portal. The deprecation of the portal, dosnt mean the existing functionality will fail, which have the alternatives.